# debugging python web service

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using the instructions found [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/user_agent.html), to try to inspect the HTTP commands being sent to my webserver.

However, I am not seeing the HTTP commands being printed on the console as suggested in the tutorial. Does anyone know how to display/debug  the HTTP commands at the CLI?

I am running Python 2.6.5 on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Let me get this clear - you want to inspect all commands sent to your webserver or just like in the example - the commands using urllib, which you are sending yourself?

Comment: I just want to see the HTTP commands being sent when I use urlib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The tutorial information seems to be deprecated.

Correct way to debug with `urllib2` nowadays is:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://diveintomark.org/xml/atom.xml')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))    
feeddata = opener.open(request).read()
```

Debugging with `urllib` works the old way though.

Comment: Ah, you see my dear fellow, its people like you that make SO the great site that it is!. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: also note that if you're using SSL (an https:// URL), you must use an HTTPSHandler instead of an HTTPHandler. took me a while to figure *that* one out. example: opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel = 1))