# How do I debug HTTPS post requests from my commandline program?

Tags: python, http, networking, http-post

I am trying to write a Python program that POSTs a build request to a Jenkins server over HTTPS. I have tried PycURL, which works well, but am now trying to replace that with standard library facilities. The revised program receives a 404 response from the server however, so I would like to inspect both versions of the program's actual POST requests to the server (with and without PycURL) to see what's different.

Which tool can I use to capture my program's POST requests and analyze them?

Comment: Take a look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404654/debugging-python-web-service

Comment: You may use wireshark program. It's opensource and crossplatform network analyzer and it can show and parse many protocols.

Comment: @Malvolio That technique doesn't help me so long as I'm not using urllib2 (what I use is PycURL and httplib2).

Comment: urllib2 uses httplib2 for all its communication.

Comment: @Malvolio: How can it, when urllib2 is standard and httplib2 is not? Besides, it still doesn't help me in the PycURL case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

But wireshark gives dumps overwhelming amount of data.

So choose any packet in the dump.

Right click and **Follow Stream**.

[Read good tutorial here.](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-sniff-network-traffic-wireshark)

Comment: Any suggestion for finding packets stemming from my particular program?

Comment: I think I found the request I was looking for, can I somehow decrypt it, considering it's HTTPS?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: I'll try to analyze the same request over HTTP instead, Wireshark looks pretty good so far.

Comment: Good luck! Its the best thing!

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify a proxy with your application then take a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). It will man in the middle HTTPS requests and give you a good overview of exactly whats going in and out. As also mentioned [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) may be of use to you if you cannot use a proxy as it will capture the raw traffic but it can be fiddly to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the program to dump the traffic tcpdump or WireShark